# Where can i find Column Statistics in Redshift?

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, table-statistics

Taking into consideration an example of hive tables / databricks:

If I need column level statistics what i do is:

```
ANALYZE TABLE <db.table> COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS <column>


DESCRIBE EXTENDED <db.table> <column>
```

Similarly I've seen there's no command called `DESCRIBE` in Redshift.

Now i'm expecting the same workaround in Redshift.

What is the output I am expecting:

Statistics like:

1. Min
2. Max
3. Avg Length
4. Max Length
5. Distinct
6. Null

What internal tables do i need to look into? Also if I need to join multiple internal tables to get the aforementioned stats.